# Group homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and $D_{2n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ has elements of order $2n$, while $D_{2n}$, a dihedral group of order $2n$, only has elements of maximum order $n$, there is no isomorphism between the two groups. But I got confused.

If two groups are of the same order, then there must exist a bijection between the groups. And one can define a homomorphism, which does not necessarily preserve orders of elements between the groups. Then why does this homomorphism have to be non-injective?

Comment: "And one can define a homomorphism..." How? From the bijection? (Hint: You can't.)

Comment: I think I'm missing something about homomorphisms. What is it that does not allow to define a homomorphism in the above case?

Comment: What is it that does? What properties do you think homomorphisms have? They aren't just functions

Comment: $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$. A homomorphism must respect group structures. But I don't know how to see that a homomorphism cannot be defined between certain groups. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: These two groups are not isomorphic. This means that every bijection is not a group homomorphism, and every group homomorphism is not bijective.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is abelian while $D_{2n}$ is not. Can you see now why they cannot be isomorphic?

Comment: And the problem did not say there were no homomorphism.

Comment: Yes, I can understand (in fact, I thought about it too) that since $Z_{2n}$ is abelian, while $D_{2n}$ is not, an isomorphism is impossible. However, I'm still curious as to how one can prove that a homomorphism does not exist between the two groups.

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is not abelian under subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ of order $2n$.  So $g^0$, $g^1$, $g^2$, ..., $q^{2n-1}$ are distinct.  But if there is a homomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ to some subgroup of $D_{2n}$, then, since $\phi(g)$ has order less than $2n$, $\phi(g^0)$, $\phi(g)$, $\phi(g^2)=[\phi(g)]^2$, ..., $\phi(g^{2n-1})=[\phi(g)]^{2n-1}$ cannot be distinct.  Hence $\phi$ is not injective.

Comment: But a homomorphism does not have to preserve order? That is, for an element $z$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ of order $i$, $\phi(z)$ does not have to be of order $i$.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to.  For example, if $g$ is an element of order $2n$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and $h$ is an element of order $n$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then $\phi(g^i)=h^i$ defines a homomorphism.  You can see this because $\phi(g^ig^j)=\phi(g^{i+j})=h^{i+j}=h^ih^j$, and so the multiplicative structure is preserved.

Comment: I'm still wondering why can't there be an injective homomorphism between two groups specified above if a homomorphism does not have to preserve order? I mean how can one prove this?

Comment: I think this is proved in my answer.  What happens in the example in my comment above is that $e$ and $g^n$ both map to the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  So $\phi$ in that example is not injective.

Comment: So, a homomorphism does exist in the case of the two groups, but it's just that it's not injective? I was just confused a little bit because one of the commenters said that there's no homomorphism between the two groups.

Comment: There is no homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and $D_{2n}$.  A map between finite sets of the same size that is not injective is also not surjective.  The  image of any homomorphic map from $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ to $D_{2n}$ must be a proper subgroup of $D_{2n}$.

Comment: Can there be a non-surjective homomorphism?

Comment: A homomorphism needn't be surjective.

Comment: If a homomorphism needn't be surjective nor injective, then why can't there be a homomorphism between $D_{2n}$ and $Z_{2n}$? Sorry, I still don't see why.

Comment: There is no homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ with $D_{2n}$ as its image.  But $D_{2n}$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and there is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ to $D_{2n}$ with this subgroup as its image.  Whether this counts as a homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and $D_{2n}$ depends on the meaning of "between".